# Which approach should i opt for?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

in my scenario I have to  extract data from sql server  and migrate it into sharepoint  , as soon  as a record is entered into the database I have to run my console application that executes the migration process , my client gave me  a strict requirement that he wants the data to be migrated right away as it is entered in the database .

there are two possible ways , I think this task can be done by

1 scheduling the console application to run after every 1 minute

2 database pooling (I have only heard about this thing ,can you guys help me out with references to articles and other material on the internet that are relevant to this approach )

so what do you guys think , which approach should I opt for  ?

Answer (score 1):

.NET has has a SQL notification
That would be more efficient than polling

[Using SqlNotificationRequest to Subscribe to Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190270%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

And are you sure a console app it the correct approach?
Consider a s service.

Also consider SISS as Joe recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably look into an SSIS package that does the migration, and possibly execute it from a trigger on insert into the table. That way there's no delay, and everything is done in one place.

I don't exactly know how you'd accomplish this - not a SSIS guy - but I know it can be done.

If the migration takes a long time to execute, or if records get inserted in the database rather quickly, this might not be a good idea, since they might get inserted faster than they can be migrated. If that's the case, a scheduled job to pull the new records in a batch would definitely be the way to go - either a Windows service that's constantly running and firing an event with a timer, or a Windows scheduled task that runs every x minutes, or a SQL Server job that runs every x minutes - at that point, it really doesn't matter which you choose.